# Best setup for an App with touch events and page transitions

Tags: android, ios, windows, mobile

I've been looking for the best way to setup/choose my mobile development libraries. It's been giving me an headache of all the options there are.

I've tried UXI, Zepto, JQMobile, Sencha, and a couple more.

What i'm looking for is a highly cross device supported lightweight library. I only want to use it for eventHandling focussed on mobile events like swipe. And i'd love to use some page transitions.

Can anyone talk some sense in me?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind going over whats wrong with Zepto and JQM?

Zepto is extremely lightweight and deals with animations beautifully. Unfortunately the documentation isn't so great so figuring it out is a bit tricky. I'd go with this if you have the patience to learn it.

JQM is less lightweight but has *great* documentation and a lot of people able to help you here on stackoverflow. Its perfect for your eventHandling and transitions.

Sencha has very nice features but oh my god is it ever different than anything I've ever used. if you can figure it out, you can make some beautiful apps but I would stray away from this due to how heavyweight it is vs what you want to do.

[Here is something](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/using-the-zepto-js-touch-events-plugin-for-more-responsive-phonegap-apps-without-zepto) that will help you with really speedy touch events / event handling though.

Comment: Love Zepto but the problem with zepto is that is doesn't support the windows phone.
JqMobile forces me to build their way, and I want to build my may. JQM also uses the data atributes which I want to use for my controller.